# Wired Network Problem in Ubuntu 12.04.2, Ethernet controller- Realtek PCIe GBE Family netwok controller

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet, realtek

**"sudo lshw -C network"**, this command results into

PCI (sysfs)
  *-network

```
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:9a100000-9a103fff
```

*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 03
   serial: c8:0a:a9:4c:dc:84
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw ip=70.70.70.78 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:94104000-94104fff memory:94100000-94103fff memory:94110000-9411ffff
```

and "**lspci -nn**" this results into

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 02)

00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port [8086:0045] (rev 02)

00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 05)

00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 05)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 05)

00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:3b44] (rev 05)

00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:3b4a] (rev 05)

00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 8 [8086:3b50] (rev 05)

00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 05)

00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev a5)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b03] (rev 05)

00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:3b2f] (rev 05)

00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30] (rev 05)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G98M [GeForce G105M] [10de:0a68] (rev a2)

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be3] (rev a1)

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)

04:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller [197b:2380]

04:00.1 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2382]

04:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2381]

04:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller [197b:2383]

04:00.4 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller [197b:2384]

ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)

ff:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2d01] (rev 02)

ff:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2d10] (rev 02)

ff:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2d11] (rev 02)

ff:02.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d12] (rev 02)

ff:02.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d13] (rev 02)
```

Please help me, I have already spend too much time in reading blogs so that I can also find some solution to my problem. But I didn't find one.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your ethernet card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0200

Comment: I have added the result of command "lspci -nn", I am actually new to Ubuntu...so please guide me...And if you want any more detail then please let me know

Comment: Your wired ethernet shows a driver, an interface and an IP address where it is connected! What, exactly, is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I don't exactly know what might be the problem but the ethernet driver being shown on ubuntu 12.04.2 is r8169, but as i can see that my system is having RTL8111/8168B. If you could find out a solution to this problem, I'll be greatful to you

Comment: That is the name of the usual driver for your device. It's funny but true that the driver for RTL8111/8168B is called, in Linux, r8169. Is it working as expected? It looks very good to me.

Comment: Actually, it's not...I don't know what has happened to it. I seem to have made no mistake...but still i am not able to access the internet on Ubuntu 12.04.2

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of these commands: nm-tool and also: ifconfig. Thanks.

Comment: Finally it worked. Thanks. Actually in firefox there was a default setting of proxy usage. I just selected "No Proxy" and it is working fine. Once again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ethernet seems to be working fine. Please check 'no proxy' in Firefox.